# Ruby: can you send a socket as a parameter?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a long ruby script running on a machine and I thought of re-organizing it by dividing it into small functions and sending the socket as a parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def prepare data, my_socket
  # some calculations 
  my_socket.write data
end

# execution starts here 

tcpsocket = TCPSocket.open host, port
data = "xxx"
prepare(data, tcpsocket)
```

Unfortunately I can't test.

EDIT: Now that I understood that I shouldn't do that (I will read on the subject later), this is what I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def prepare data
  my_array = []
  # some calculations 
  my_array << data
end

# execution starts here 

tcpsocket = TCPSocket.open host, port
data = "xxx"
my_array = prepare data
my_array.each do |m|
  my_socket.write m
end
```

Comment: WHY do you want to do this? It won't be valid on another machine.

Comment: that's one script/file, just to divide the execution into multiple parts, it's too long ...

Comment: Please do not define a method called `send` in Ruby. That is a reserved method name and will conflict with `Object`'s `send` method.

Comment: that was just for an example. I will edit my question.

Comment: Divide what? You can't reuse the same socket on a different machine.

Comment: it's one script running on a machine. ?

Comment: You need to explain your question and scenario a LOT better. Reusing a single socket inside a single app is doable, but you're going about it the hard way. As is, we can't really tell what you are doing. Do NOT tell us in comments, instead edit your question and make it more understandable.

Comment: I'm assuming that `my_array.do` is really `my_array.each do`.

Comment: yes sorry! corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcpsocket` is a local identifier (file descriptor) for a given socket-endpoint.

You would not achieve anything by sending the file descriptor of one host to another host. Without the kernel (or process) hosting the file-descriptor, `tcpsocket` means nothing. Typically, the kernel would have a mapping of file-descriptor and the socket structure. If you send the `tcpsocket` file-descriptor to the other side, the other side would not have the corresponding socket structure.

Accordingly, operations on the passed file-descriptor would fail with a bad file-descriptor error. In the worst case, if the process on the remote host has another file-descriptor with the same value, then this would cause unexpected things!

Comment: It's in the same file, one script. But it's too long and I thought of dividing it. Should I not?

Comment: Even if it is in the same file, different copies of the file would be run on the client host and the server host.  Basically, we should call socket open for both client and server separately and in most cases, they would be called separately on different machines in the network.

Comment: "this would cause unexpected things!" is a very, very mild way of saying it. It could corrupt a file or a database that happens to have the same descriptor, cause apps to crash mysteriously, and, in general make your life extremely miserable once the system administrator/DBA/fellow developers find out what was done.

Comment: okay I won't ... I didn't know that's why I asked. Thank you everyone. I'll just leave it alone.

Comment: @theTinMan (+1) I agree -- there is no limit to the amount of damage :-) Btw, thnx for the edit.

Comment: @nemo, it's not that what you want to do is bad, it's just how you're going about it and how you explained it. I'd recommend thinking about what you want to accomplish and then create a new question based on an improved explanation. Show a bit more code too. Remember, a socket is a file-descriptor basically, so you can assign that to a variable or a constant or a pool of descriptors in an array, and your code can access them as a shared resource. You could even open multiple sockets, and create a queue of them you rotate through.

Comment: I agree, It was basically that I saw this infinitely long file and I was thinking of re-organizing. I did re-organize by doing something else. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I added to the question what I ended up doing ...